# this в модуле nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Кто-нибудь может объяснить или дать ссылку на объяснение почему в файле в файле модуля `this` возвращает `{}` тогда как внутри любой функции `this` возвращает объект `global`?

Чуть подробнее:
В консоли, например, все в целом понятно, мы находимся в среде но не внутри какого-либо модуля

```
> this
<ref *1> Object [global] {
  global: [Circular *1],
  clearInterval: [Function: clearInterval],
  clearTimeout: [Function: clearTimeout],
  setInterval: [Function: setInterval],
  setTimeout: [Function: setTimeout] {
    [Symbol(nodejs.util.promisify.custom)]: [Function (anonymous)]
  },
  queueMicrotask: [Function: queueMicrotask],
  clearImmediate: [Function: clearImmediate],
  setImmediate: [Function: setImmediate] {
    [Symbol(nodejs.util.promisify.custom)]: [Function (anonymous)]
  }
}
```

однако внутри модуля когда я создаю вот такой файл например:

```
function context() {
  console.log(this);
}

console.log(this);
context();
```

вывод получается вот такой:

```
{}
<ref *1> Object [global] {
  global: [Circular *1],
  clearInterval: [Function: clearInterval],
  clearTimeout: [Function: clearTimeout],
  setInterval: [Function: setInterval],
  setTimeout: [Function: setTimeout] {
    [Symbol(nodejs.util.promisify.custom)]: [Function (anonymous)]
  },
  queueMicrotask: [Function: queueMicrotask],
  clearImmediate: [Function: clearImmediate],
  setImmediate: [Function: setImmediate] {
    [Symbol(nodejs.util.promisify.custom)]: [Function (anonymous)]
  }
}
```

то бишь пустой объект для this в модуле и объект global для this в функции
Кто-нибудь знает почему это так и где в доке NodeJS это описано?

Comment: Смотреть на this в repl и думать что из этого можно сделать какой-то вывод в корне неверно.

Comment: `this` - внутри модуля - это объект модуля

Comment: @AlexeyTen это локальный терминал, умник

Comment: @АртемНиколаев и что? Это не repl что ли?

Comment: @Grundy это известно, вопрос почему в том же модуле контекст исполнения функции ссылается на global а не на объект модуля

Comment: @АртемНиколаев, не в том же модуле, а внутри функции. Внутри функции - все согласно спецификации.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По историческим причинам в модуле `this === module.exports`.
Но пользоваться этим не рекомендуется.

https://nodejs.org/api/deprecations.html#deprecations_dep0092_top_level_this_bound_to_module_exports